# How to find format of sscanf input assembly

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering

Im trying to figure out what format sscanf function is asking for in assembly. I think it wants two inputs but im not sure if those should be both decimal or string etc.

Ive tried x/s and x/d 0x400c30 but i got \377%z4. Where can i look so it says %d or %s etc? Thanks in advance!

```
Dump of assembler code for function phase_4:
   0x000000000040101e <+0>: sub    $0x18,%rsp
   0x0000000000401022 <+4>: lea    0xc(%rsp),%rcx
   0x0000000000401027 <+9>: lea    0x8(%rsp),%rdx
   0x000000000040102c <+14>:    mov    $0x4027cd,%esi
   0x0000000000401031 <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x0000000000401036 <+24>:    callq  0x400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt> //???
   0x000000000040103b <+29>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x000000000040103e <+32>:    jne    0x40104c <phase_4+46>
   0x0000000000401040 <+34>:    mov    0xc(%rsp),%eax
   0x0000000000401044 <+38>:    sub    $0x2,%eax
   0x0000000000401047 <+41>:    cmp    $0x2,%eax
   0x000000000040104a <+44>:    jbe    0x401051 <phase_4+51>
   0x000000000040104c <+46>:    callq  0x401554 <explode_bomb>
   0x0000000000401051 <+51>:    mov    0xc(%rsp),%esi
   0x0000000000401055 <+55>:    mov    $0x7,%edi
   0x000000000040105a <+60>:    callq  0x400fe6 <func4>
   0x000000000040105f <+65>:    cmp    0x8(%rsp),%eax
   0x0000000000401063 <+69>:    je     0x40106a <phase_4+76>
   0x0000000000401065 <+71>:    callq  0x401554 <explode_bomb>
   0x000000000040106a <+76>:    add    $0x18,%rsp
   0x000000000040106e <+80>:    retq
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming x86 here. The AT&T syntax is unfamiliar to me, but sscanf's second argument, the format string, goes in the rsi register. The string you're looking for, seems to reside at address 4027cd.

```
0x000000000040102c <+14>:    mov    $0x4027cd,%esi
0x0000000000401031 <+19>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000401036 <+24>:    callq  0x400c30 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt> //???
```

Try to examine that address instead

Comment: thats what I was thinking, and youre right! tried it out and got %d %d. Thank you!